# Prevent command line argument from displaying in bash history or ps -ef with bash script

Tags: java, bash, unix, password-protection, ps

I have some java code that executes a bash script which in turn is executing a command line tool that requires command line arguments in order to run.

One of these command line arguments to this tool is a plain text password.

The script is something like:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# script.sh
# some setup code 

<cli-tool-executable> -arg1 <arg1> -arg2 <arg2> ... -password <password>
```

and i'm invoking this from java code via [apache commons exec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/index.html) by doing something like

```java
CommandLine commandLine = new CommandLine("bash");

// bash script that runs the tool
commandLine.addArgument("script.sh");

// add other arguments
commandLine.addArgument(...);

// execute
new DefaultExecutor().execute(commandLine);
```

Given this in its present state, if I were to run `ps -ef` or look at the bash history, I would be able to see the command line arguments provided to the cli tool, including the password, as plain text, which is obviously not great.

Ideally, I'd want it so that the password is obfuscated in some way or not show up at all.

I've spent the better half of a day trying to look up other solutions to this, and in the process have discovered that:

- There are some potentially hacky ways to do this with C code which are not necessarily safe or recommended
- It is not desirable to ever pass in passwords in this way (quite obviously), and always better to do it via a file that has its permissions controlled in some secure way, or through the environment and passing in as stdin, or via just code itself. Unfortunately, neither is an option for me (the tool does not support it - it just expects a command line parameter called -password with a string password, that doesn't read off any environment variables or anything similar).
- I'm still not fully sure whether what I'm trying to do is entirely possible

I've tried putting stuff in environment variables and passing it to the -password argument, I tried putting it in a file and trying to do `cat passwordfile` into the password argument, but in all cases I've tried it doesn't seem to not show the password argument.

Does anyone have any ideas/recommendations on this? Thank you.

Comment: You can make it easier to reproduce: When you run `secret=7;sleep $secret &`, you will find `sleep 7` with `ps -f`. How can you avoid this?

Comment: I didnt test https://serverfault.com/a/592941, is this working for you?

Answer (score 0):

May be it's a long shot but you could run your command inside a [docker bash](https://hub.docker.com/_/bash) instance (with proper security setup). For example, with a `Dockerfile`

```
FROM bash:4.4
COPY script.sh /
CMD ["bash", "/script.sh"]
```

As an alternative to explore, there's a [docker engine API](https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/examples/)(click on `HTTP` tab), basically most of what a docker client does.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I'm not entirely sure that would work for my use case due to specific restrictions with regards to environments the script will be running in

Comment: AFAIK docker is as safe as the host is running in. If the script can run on a given host, it can run inside docker on the same host.

Comment: AFAIK Commands running in a docker are shown in the `ps -ef` of the host.

Comment: There's always hope, seems [hidepid](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264700/200657) can be used to rise the security on this case. Unless you don't trust root lol